# How to get all the properties of a specified type in a class without reflection

Tags: c#, oop, class, reflection, interface

I have a class which is has tons of properties. Most of them are of custom types. I want to get all those properties, type of whose interface is same.

```
Public class abc:IamLegend
{
    few properties
}

public class def:IamLegend
{
    few properties
}

public class on_which_iamworking
{
    public abc propabc{ get; set; }
    public def propdef{ get; set; }
    public someothertype propother{ get; set; }
}
```

I want something which returns propabc and propdef.

I know how to do it using reflection, but I am looking for another way.

I am working on c# 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use reflection?

Comment: "I want to get the properties, but I don't want to use the system designed to do this".

Comment: Client's excuse is he don't want to make it heavy(slower)

Comment: Sounds like you have a poorly-informed client.

Comment: Blaming this on the client is poor form. It's your job as a developer to *explain* these things to the client. That's why they're paying you; they're not the professional software development expert.

Comment: Actually they ARE professional software developers and they believe REFLECTION IS SLOW, I beleive rather than arguing its better to focus on the problem.

Comment: The solution to the problem as you're framing it is "You Can't". They might be 'professional' software developers with a small P, but lacking the understanding to realise that 'slow' is relative and is irrelevant compared to the importance of using established methods designed to solve the problem isn't very "Professional" at all.

Comment: @Manvinder - This is possible without using the *slow* classes from `System.Relfection`, I would suggest looking into the Mono.Cecil library to help you. In my experience it performs better performance and is **not** .NET Reflection (in the literal sense). There is actually a very helpful wrapper class that is distributed as part of the [Mono.Addins](http://monoaddins.codeplex.com/) project called `Mono.Reflection` with a similar API without the aftertaste.

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid that this is not possible at runtime without using reflection. That's what reflection is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of reflection is that it is slow. If you don't want to use reflection only because of it's slowness, you could make caching of your property list in some static property or class. I used this tecknique widely in similar problems and there wasn't any problems with perfomance.

If you have holy war against reflection, you could create a special util that parses C# file (or builds your prokects, loads output assembly and use reflection, but only before build, not in run-time), finds needed properties and writes it into autogenerated file (maybe also C# code file) as static-class array-property initializer. And call that util on pre-build event of your project. Then you'll get all needed properties completely without reflections =) (but I wouldn't do that)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's two ways:

1/

```
 return new List<string> { "propabc", "propdev" };
```

2/ Reflection :P

If you need to retrieve the list of properties many times and are afraid of the performance impact, compute the list only once and store it in a static property (as the list of properties of a class won't change during runtime).

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative approach for components. It is [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) for classes that implement `IComponent`. I believe that is used by WPF.